# Dataframe with all possible Sums of two arrays in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Lets say i have two arrays

```
array_1 = [10,20,30]
array_2 = [50,60,70]
```

Dataframe i need as Output:

```
        10   20   30
50      60   70   80
60      70   80   90
70      80   90  100
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. What did you try so far ?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) addition

```
>>> np.add.outer(array_1, array_2)
```

To create the data frame:

```
pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=array_2, index=array_1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `numpy.ndarray` and broadcasting:

```
>>> length = len(array_1)
>>> pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(np.array(array_1), (length, 1)) + np.reshape(np.array(array_2), (1, length)))
    0   1    2
0  60  70   80
1  70  80   90
2  80  90  100
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(np.array(array_1), (len(array_1), 1)) + np.reshape(np.array(array_2), (1, len(array_2))))`   Worked for me, thanks! Only had to replace _length_ with `len(array_1)`

Comment: @Andre whoops, forgot to put that in when pasting code.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Marcus's answer but using newaxis. Reshape array_1 to (3,1) and array_2 to (1,3). The resulting sum of the two arrays will have shape (3,3).

```
df = pd.DataFrame(array_1[np.newaxis, :] + array_2[:, np.newaxis], index = array_1, columns = array_2)

    50  60  70
10  60  70  80
20  70  80  90
30  80  90  100
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two short methods using `ix_`

```
A = sum(np.ix_([40, 0], [10, 20, 30]))
pd.DataFrame(sum(np.ix_(*A)), *A)
#     10  20   30
# 50  60  70   80
# 60  70  80   90
# 70  80  90  100
```

or `c_`

```
A2, A1 = np.c_[[40, 0]] + [10, 20, 30]
pd.DataFrame(np.c_[A2] + A1, A2, A1)
#     10  20   30
# 50  60  70   80
# 60  70  80   90
# 70  80  90  100
```